# Is there a JavaScript WYSIWYG that leverages jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I have looked at [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), [FCKeditor](http://www.fckeditor.net), [YUI Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/), [NicEdit](http://www.nicedit.com/) and some others, but I was wondering if there is one out there that utilises jQuery? I mean, I already use jQuery in all my projects, and it seemed it'd be useful to have a WYSIWYG editor that used it also. This should result in a smaller file size.

I understand if one doesn't exist (as they were probably developed before JS frameworks were popular, and changing the codebase now is too much work), or simply for easy deployment (no dependency on any framework).

So, does one exist, and is it any good?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[jquery wysiwyg](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/)

Comment: Other Stackoverflow users have suggested that jwysiwyg is too buggy for production use. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754016/is-jwysiwyg-editor-too-buggy-for-production-use

Answer (score 3):

I've been using for some time editor of [imperavi redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/). Quick, easy, may not be quite functional, but a constantly evolving

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a full blown WYSIWYG editor, but it sure is handy if you need something to do markup languages like Markdown, BB Code, Textile, some Wiki syntax or even raw HTML.

[markItUp! Universal Markup Editor](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

Answer (score 0):

theres a lightweight plugin by Batiste Bieler [here](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html)