# Is jWYSIWYG editor too buggy for production use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwysiwyg

After reading the comments on this site:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jwysiwyg-jquery-inline-content-editor-plugin/

There is a bit of consensus that [jWYSIWYG](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/) editor is *too buggy* (especially in the last few recent comments). Has anyone had experience with it in a large production site?

I haven't run a huge sample of markup through it yet, but so far it has seemed to do the job fine.

Comment: If only it was easy to toggle "Show HTML" or "Show Source" version.

Comment: Make sure you read @dimoooon's answer below - the project is no longer active on google code and has moved to github - http://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/downloads, seems very active and is documented.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have been using jwysiwyg (https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg) for about 4 months now on several production sites and I have to say that it is the best lightweight wysiwyg editor that I have used.  It is small, fast, and reliable.  I strongly recommend it for anyone that doesn't need a full-featured editor.  If you need to work with complex source code and html markup then this may not be for you, but for business-level users it works very well.

I am guessing that the original question and all comments until here are out-dated.  This is a great plugin.

Comment: Yep, seems like a lot has changed. +1 to bubble up the good news :)

Answer (score 6):

### This answer may no longer reflect the current state of the project.

Checkout out the current version on https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg and decide yourself.

---

I don't know the project but I conclude: **Don't use it** (at least at the moment)

- the google code page [jwysiwyg](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/) contains no documentation
- the download also doesn't contain any
- there are [91 open issues](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/issues/list) in the tracker (which for such a small project isn't a good indicator)
- last commit (r33) was on the 21. September 2009
- the second-last commit (r32) was on 21. April 2009
- so no frequent updates to codebase either
- no new download file (current is *jwysiwyg-0.5.zip* which dates from January 2009), although he made 3 commits after publishing v0.5 of which:

  - 2 contain fixes for issues
  - 1 restructures directory layout and adds a minimal example to the codebase

Comment: hmm good answer. If I do decide to use this, I'll add my own answer about any issues I came across with it. Thanks for looking into it for me!

Comment: Hmm what's the downvote for? For those not able to understand  **at least at the moment** I updated my post. My answer was correct at the time I gave it and reflected the projects status at that moment of time

Answer (score 6):

are u tried to find some other place where this editor can be located? for example: http://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/downloads  ? There u can find v. 0.9 released few days ago

Answer (score 1):

jwysiwyg has grown year-to-year development activity and community.

It hosted on GitHub more than1 year, so feel free to use, fork, patch and do pull request.

Comment: Are you the main contributor? Can turn this into a full answer and explain how jwysiwyg is (hopefully) now stable?