# WYSIWYG with jquery and MD output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg, markdown

I am looking for and editor which uses jquery and capable of:

- display editable html content, instead of editable source code because I want to edit long content, so it's hard to find something in code what I see in the displayed content... (I can accept alternatives too)
- functions like: h1-6, paragraph, list, link, image, file attachment
- easy customizable: need to insert custom widgets like google maps, etc... to the edited page, I don't need to display the real content, a screenshot of google maps is enough in the editor
- can generate markdown (MD) output (not so important if the generated html is well convertable)
- can be html5, old browsers are not important.

There are a lot of editors, and I cannot choose. I thought maybe you can recommend a good editor you are satisfied with and has those features ...

Comment: What's wrong with writing the code yourself? A lot of times with those WYSIWYG editors you end up with WAY more code than you actually need. Also, have you taken a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707916/is-there-a-javascript-wysiwyg-that-leverages-jquery?rq=1

Comment: I usually try to avoid reinventing the wheel, and I don't have unlimited time ... I'll check that question, thanks!